# MongoDB query to return an object of object which stores individual documents along with sum of few fields in all documents

Tags: mongodb

I want to build a MongoDB query that $match on the first stage of the pipeline and then returns an object of object, where the first object is $project of a few common fields and next object is sum aggregation of the fields which are not common, the fields will be mentioned in the pipeline. For example, given 2 documents after the match pipeline -

```
{
  _id: "6284b519313f50001595fe37",
  "bus": "EXAMP",
  "city": "Udaypur",
  "AccountName": "Examp Transport Service",
  "agencyName": "Sbb",
  "depotName": "RAYAPUR HUBLI",
  "CashCollection": 8,
  "Collection": 30,
  "IssueTicket": 5,
  "PassengerCount": 4,
  "TicketCount": 4
}
{
  _id: "62684658703e9e00136ec64c",
  "bus": "EXAMP",
  "city": "Kanpur",
  "AccountName": "Example Transport Service",
  "agencyName": "BBS",
  "depotName": "RAYAPUR HUBLI",
  "CashCollection": 10,
  "Collection": 20,
  "IssueTicket": 7,
  "PassengerCount": 5,
  "TicketCount": 4
}
```

So I would need to store few fields of both of these documents in the first object [bus, city, AccountName, agencyName, depotName], and in the next, I would need the aggregation of fields [CashCollection, Collection, IssueTicket, PassengerCount, TicketCount]. So my object of object should look like the below -

```
{
  result: [
    {
     _id: "6284b519313f50001595fe37",
     "bus": "EXAMP",
     "city": "Kanpur",
     "AccountName": "Examp Transport Service",
     "agencyName": "Sbb",
     "depotName": "RAYAPUR HUBLI",
    },
    {
     _id: "62684658703e9e00136ec64c",
     "bus": "EXAMP",
     "city": "Kanpur",
     "AccountName": "Example Transport Service",
     "agencyName": "BBS",
     "depotName": "RAYAPUR HUBLI"
    }
  ],
  aggregates: {
   "CashCollection": 18,
  "Collection": 50,
  "IssueTicket": 12,
  "PassengerCount": 9,
  "TicketCount": 8
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb query to return object of object where the object is aggregation of few fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696926/mongodb-query-to-return-object-of-object-where-the-object-is-aggregation-of-few)

Comment: This is the same question answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696926/mongodb-query-to-return-object-of-object-where-the-object-is-aggregation-of-few/72697679#72697679 . Hope, this may help to modify

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$group: {
  _id: "test",
  results: {
    $push: {
      city: "$city",
      bus: "$bus",
      _id: "$_id"
    }
  },
  CashCollection: {
    $sum: "$CashCollection"
  },
  Collection: {
    $sum: "$Collection"
  },
  IssueTicket: {
    $sum: "$IssueTicket"
  },
  
}
},
{
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  results: 1,
  aggregates: {
    CashCollection: "$CashCollection",
    Collection: "$Collection",
    IssueTicket: "$IssueTicket"
   }
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Group with push to sum the common counters.
2. Project the desired subfields.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YytEj09A_Gk)